How can I set the asset icon of a ScriptableObject depending on its properties?
I want to set an icon for scriptable-object according to it's properties.
I succeeded, but the end result was not what I wanted.
I used RenderStaticPreview in it's editor script and this is the result:

First: I don't need the frame around the icon.
Second: when I turn the view list, the scriptable-object icon return to default.

The code:
[CustomEditor(typeof(Example))]
public class ExampleEditor : Editor
{
    public override void OnInspectorGUI()
    {
        Example e = (Example)target;

        EditorGUI.BeginChangeCheck();

        // Example has a single arg called PreviewIcon which is a Texture2D
        e.PreviewIcon = (Texture2D)
                EditorGUILayout.ObjectField(
                    "Thumbnail",                    // string
                    e.PreviewIcon,                  // Texture2D
                    typeof(Texture2D),              // Texture2D object, of course
                    false                           // allowSceneObjects
                );

        if (EditorGUI.EndChangeCheck())
        {
            EditorUtility.SetDirty(e);
            AssetDatabase.SaveAssets();
            Repaint();
        }
    }

    public override Texture2D RenderStaticPreview(string assetPath, Object[] subAssets, int width, int height)
    {
        Example example = (Example)target;

        if (example == null || example.PreviewIcon == null)
            return null;

        // example.PreviewIcon must be a supported format: ARGB32, RGBA32, RGB24,
        // Alpha8 or one of float formats
        Texture2D tex = new Texture2D(width, height);
        EditorUtility.CopySerialized(example.PreviewIcon, tex);

        return tex;
    }
}

The result I want:

In list view:

I edited the script import settings to set this icon in the previous picture to show you the result I want, but this method will not help me because I need to set the icon according to the scriptable-object properties.

Maybe try this https://github.com/ligofff/SimpleTools-CustomSOIcons ?
Or this thread : https://discussions.unity.com/t/custom-scriptableobject-icons-thumbnail/543414/47
